# Get value after end of last / in excel using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i want to get the last value after / in excel.

```
www.google.com/new/oldpage.php
www.google.com/new/hello/wright.html
www.facebook.com/face/newface/demo.php
```

from the above link i want to separate the pagename
for eg. from 1 url output should be www.google.com/new/ 2nd www.google.com/new/hello/ and so 
i used RIGHT formula but we can define only static. pls. provide if any one has the solution.

Comment: so you are using function "Right". What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A1 is `www.google.com/new/oldpage.php`, use this code to get `www.google.com/new/`:

```
=LEFT( A1, FIND( "|", SUBSTITUTE( A1, "/", "|", LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","")) ) ) )
```

Use this code to get `oldpage.php`:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","")))))
```

As you can see, you need to `SUBSTITUTE` some chars before calling the `FIND` method.

Depending on your regional options, you must change "," (comma) in the formula for ";" (semicolon).

Comment: thnx for answer but i want only the directory path not extenstion.

Comment: Sorry... In that case, the solution is easier. I've updated the answer.

Comment: hi i tried your given code but its not working. #Value Error.

Comment: Sorry again. My fault. You need to calculate the number of substitutions. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula,

```
=MID(A16,SEARCH("^^",SUBSTITUTE(A16,"/","^^",LEN(A16)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A16,"/",""))))+1,999)
```

Comment: `=trim(right(substitute(a1&"/", "/", rept(" ", 99)), 199))` By appending a slash to the original string, you can bypass all of the error control to some degree and return the original not slashed value if there is no slash to found. It's not useful but it also should be a hyperlink subaddress.

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't provide a formula for reverse string searches so the following must be used

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("/",A1)),A1,RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))))
```